# How to give user an option to customize site according to their own needs?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm creating a website of my own, in which I would like to add a feature where user can customize the site according to them like, by changing background color, font, font-color etc by using a customization widget. (just like twitter having this feature). I tried to Google to find any external api's for this but didn't got any. My project is based on Angular2. The question is not based on programming, but it will be very much helpful if someone can suggest me any approaches for this idea. Thank you!

Comment: Just give them a way to specify their own CSS style-rules and then display them in-line on the page.

Comment: *Custom* data such as CSS data (which you describe -- colours, fonts, etc ) can be held in two ways, as a cookie on the visitors machine, or as data in a database.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for giving time to my question. It will be much more understanding for me if you can elaborate more. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Martin Thanks! But, I'm looking for alternative method. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 allows you to dynamically change css. you can create your own custom widgets to allow users to change css as they please. Simply bind your css values to a variable and pass it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [style.background-color]="chosenColor">
      <button (click)="Blue()">blue</button>
      <button (click)="Red()">red</button>
      <button (click)="Yellow()">yellow</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  chosenColor = "";
  constructor() {}
  Red(){
    this.chosenColor = "red"
  }
  Blue(){
    this.chosenColor = "blue"
  }
  Yellow(){
    this.chosenColor = "yellow"
  }
```

Here is a basic plunker to get you started... https://plnkr.co/edit/SdkpENReJPJJ5HRejnM9?p=preview

Comment: I know it's just an example, but why not just pass the color as a param to your method instead of having multiple methods that essentially do the same thing?

Comment: absolutely that would work too! the point is that you can just bind your css values :) and store that user info in a database somewhere, and when user logs in, bam customized to their liking

Comment: @Bean0341 Hey, thanks! I think, I just got an idea how I'm going to do this. :)

Comment: @SteveG. Thanks, for giving time to my question. You can answer too, your suggestions are welcomed. :) It will be great if you can share your method too.